# Xcode 15 missing "Select code structure"?

Tags: xcode, xcode15

I was always using <kbd>command</kbd>+click on parentheses (or braces) to select code structure on Xcode 14 and see what was in it. It looks like the option is now removed from the settings and was replace by “Jump to Definition”, which I don't want to use with <kbd>command</kbd>+click.

In Xcode 15:

[image]

In Xcode 14 :

[image]

How can I bring it back? I know I can assign a keystroke to “Selection > Balance Delimiters” or double-click the parenthesis, but it is really less handy.

Comment: I understand why they felt compelled to keep the list of choices to two (because of their weird UI design where you pick which option-click does and option-control-click automatically does the other), but, still, this is uncool. I think assigning a key binding is as close as you can get to the convenience of the old feature.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Apple removed this feature on XCode 15. You can check the release note [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode-release-notes/xcode-15-release-notes).

> The Show Code Actions command has been replaced with Show Quick Actions to quickly access any menu command. By default, Command-clicking a token in the editor now performs Jump to Definition. This can be changed in the Navigation preferences. Control-clicking a token brings up the standard contextual menu that now contains all the commands that were available in the Code Actions. (86179596)

It was replaced with Quick Actions (`Command + Shift + A`). Maybe you could try this new tool.

Comment: What a shame. I tried it, but it does not provide a function as quick as "Selects code structure".